# Odoo Import Libaray

Tags: python, orm, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I am trying to write a server action for odoo8, the server action will give me the dates between two dates based on specific interval.

So i used the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import relativedelta

startDate = object.x_start_datetime
endDate = object.x_stop_datetime
periodicity = object.x_periodicity.x_nb

visits = []
nxt   = startDate
delta = relativedelta(**{'days':periodicity})

while nxt <= endDate:
        result.append(nxt)
        nxt += delta

raise Warning('Data: ' + startDate + " | " + result)
```

I was getting error regarding the import so i modified the file (openerp/tools/safe_eval.py) to add the IMPORT_NAME and IMPORT_FROM, also i added ('datetime', 'dateutil', 'relativedelta') to the allowed modules, but now it's giving the following error:
File "/opt/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/tools/safe_eval.py", line 228, in _import
    return **import**(name, globals, locals, level)
ValueError: "'int' object does not support indexing" while evaluating

your help is appreciated.

Comment: `I was getting error regarding the import`. what error were you getting before you modified `safe_eval.py` (you shouldn't be modifying core odoo files except you're absolutely sure of what you're doing)

Comment: @danidee Before modifying the safe_eval.py it was giving an error on the import: ValueError: opcode IMPORT_NAME not allowed

and here's the full error log:
https://jpst.it/O2Ia